# How do I change the colors of editor tool tips (Quick Info) in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

One of the new features in VS 2015 is colorized editor tool tips (also called "Quick Info").  I am using the blue color theme and the identifiers in the tool tips are displayed in white on a light background making them very hard to read.  I haven't been able to find where those colors are specified in the "fonts and colors" settings. Please advise as to how to modify the tool tips color settings.

Comment: Did you by any chance find a solution for this.. I have the same problem in the VS2015 RTM version

Answer (score 1):

I am using Color Theme Editor for Visual Studio 2015.

If you select ***Tools-> Customize*** Colors and then press a small button "***Create copy of the theme***" on the theme of your choice, you can then press "***Edit theme***" on a new created custom theme, and аpparently, the background color of the tooltip was ***Environment -> CommandBarMenuBackgroundGradientBegin*** for me (you also have to press "Show all elements" button in the toolbar and use search box to see it).

IDE Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. It is better to put a full answer here. If the link stops working, the answer is lost.

Comment: Thank you. The screenshot is only for illustration purposes, but i will expand an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Color Theme Editor Extension from the 
`Tools->Extensions & Updates` menu item. 
Then you need to make a copy of the extension you need to adjust
Then you click on "Edit Theme" icon, and you change whatever you want
I think this link can help
[Visual Studio 2015 tooltip color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570310/visual-studio-2015-tooltip-color)