# Visual Studio 2015 tooltip color

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am just starting to use Visual Studio 2015, and I have run into an annoyance with the tooltip color.  The new tooltips have colorized font - which is awesome - but the background color of the tooltips clashes with my font color scheme, making it unreadable.  I've pored over the font and colors settings, and I can't seem to find a way to change this particular color.

Does anyone know if it is actually possible to change the tooltip background color in Visual Studio 2015?

Here's an example of what I'm talking about ([from here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/11/12/the-c-and-visual-basic-code-focused-ide-experience.aspx)):
[image: example]

EDIT:  There's a uservoice post for this issue [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/8814466-add-option-to-customize-intellisense-tooltip-color)

Comment: If you change the Color Theme for whole Visual Studio (dark to light etc.), tooltip background gets affected, which I assume you wouldn't prefer.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that.  I'd rather not change the entire theme, but if that's the only way to change the tooltip color then I'll do it :)

Comment: you should accept DeNappa's answer as the real answer, since it doesn't require a plugin, and works in bot 2015 & 2017

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you don't want to go the way of the plugin, I found the following setting can be used to change the background color for your tooltip:
Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Show settings for: "Environment" -> Tooltip

Comment: This is where its at for VS 2017 (no color theme extension available yet =< )

Answer (score 23):

Yes, it is possible to change the tooltip coloring in Visual Studio 2015 using the Visual Studio 2015 Color Theme Editor extension.  The Color Theme Editor is a Microsoft-authored extension available from the Tools->Extensions & Updates menu item.  There is one caveat, however: you must be using a theme (doesn't matter which one) for any of the below instructions to work...so if you have extensively customized your IDE using the Tools->Options settings without using a theme, you are out of luck.

Once you have the extension installed, go to Tools->Customize Colors and click the "Create Copy of Theme" icon in the upper right corner of your desired base theme (it looks like a painter's palette).  A new custom theme will be created using all the same settings as your selected source theme.

Click on the "Edit Theme" icon, which looks like another painter's palette with a pencil next to it.  Once in the theme editor, you will need to click the "Show All Elements" icon in the top row of the window.  Then use the Search box on the right to search for "tooltip."

You will see a collection of "Environment -- " related to tooltips.  The one named "Environment--Tooltip" is the background color for the Intellisense tips.  A value of FF525252 will yield a dark gray background that seems to play nicely with all of the colorized keywords and punctuation in the new Intellisense popups, and works well with both light and dark editor background themes.

Save your new custom theme and apply it using the Tools->Change Color Theme menu option...profit!

Comment: Awesome!  I didn't know the Color Theme Editor tool existed.  Works like a charm :).

Comment: Mine is set to dark blue but still shows as beige with unreadable white font on top. I guess I'm going to have to reset all my settings to defaults and try again from first principles. Thanks for giving me confirmation that my VS is completely broken rather than simply misconfigured - I could have spent days trying to get the impossible to work!

Comment: One snag I ran into with this is that my current theme (blue) did not seem to include fonts and colours. So when I created a copy and fixed the tooltip the fonts and colours were reset to the defaults. I had exported my fonts and colours previously, but restoring them reset the theme to blue and so also reset the tooltip background colour. I got around this by opening my exported settings and commenting out the <Theme /> element. Then I changed my theme to the copy with the fixed tooltip background and then imported my settings to get my fonts and colours back.

Comment: Actually you can import the current Fonts and Color settings into your current theme so don't despair if you've been sitting and customizing colors in the default font color dialog of Visual Studio.

Comment: @silkfire doesn't seem to work with all color types. I imported my colors and still had some that were wrong after applying a theme.

Comment: @JustinSkiles Yeah it takes some tinkering to get all items the color you want, but after that you can save and reuse your theme as your heart desires :) Are you using a dark or light theme?

Comment: @JustinSkiles Try my dark theme called "Aletheia" and tell me what you think? https://www.dropbox.com/s/jolc68umqhe3y5x/Aletheia.vstheme?dl=0

Comment: Does anyone know of how to change this exact thing for collapsed Region tooltip?  None of the tooltips in the theme editor seem to do it.

Comment: The problem with importing the color settings is that the theme is part of the settings. If you want to get back your old settings, export them before applying the new theme. Then, once the new theme is applied export those settings. Open the new settings in a text editor and search for "theme" copy the GUID into your old settings file and then import those settings.